# what is the functionality of this tag in lightning {!$Label.Number.PickOne}?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

> [Lightning Learning Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_overview.htm)

What would be the label attribute value here. when I try to render on the app i got the below message. They mentioned external. What is really meant by external. Any Idea ?

```
<ui:inputNumber label="{!$Label.Number.PickOne}" />
```

OutPut on APP :

> $Label.Number.PickOne does not exist. [[Input Box]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a custom label. You can define strings called Custom Labels to use in Apex, Visualforce, and Lightning so that you don't need to hard-code user-labels.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm

Comment: You mean here Number is a namespace .

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems to be. The Lightning docs don't seem as thorough as the old docs, so I've come across quite a few oddities like that.

Comment: Yes. When i turn number to c . Its working...   {!$Label.c.PickOne}